# Issue in getting output from xampp server database to android activity?

Tags: android, database, xampp, database-connection

I'm new to Android programming, I have developed my Android app with the help of Android Studio and xampp server, I 'm but got stuck in my last part. My application is connected to xammp server's database, when I'm entering the value of database through my Android `Activity`, it is showing "not found" but actually value is present in my database? Is there any problem with my android connectivity? Any suggestions would be very helpful for me.

```js
//this my secondActivity.java

package com.example.elwis.ucarereadytohelp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.AsyncResponse;
import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.PostResponseAsyncTask;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    final String LOG = "SecondActivity";
    Button btnCheck;
    EditText etDrugName;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        etDrugName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDrugName);
        btnCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnCheck.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        HashMap postData = new HashMap();

        String Drugname =etDrugName.getText().toString();
        postData.put("txtDrugName", "Drugname");



        PostResponseAsyncTask task1 = new PostResponseAsyncTask(SecondActivity.this, postData,
                new AsyncResponse() {
                    @Override
                    public void processFinish(String s) {
                        Log.d(LOG, s);
                        if (s.contains("Drug Found")){
                            Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Drug is Succesfully found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
        task1.execute("http://10.0.3.2/drug_list/login.php");
    }}

// and this is my login.php
    
    <?PHP 
    include_once("connection.php"); 
    if(isset($_POST['txtDrugName']) ) { 
        
  $Drugname = $_POST['txtDrugName'];
        
        $query = "SELECT * FROM Druglist WHERE Drugname = '$Drugname'"; 
        
        
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
   echo "Drug Found";
      exit;
  }
        else{
   echo "Drug Not Found";
   exit;
  }
 } 
?>
```

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: `My application is connected to xammp server's database, `. No. Its not connected to MySql. Instead it is 'connected' to php. What the php script does is out of control of your Android app.